# JavaScript: Remove movie blog content with low IMDb rating

Tags: javascript, tampermonkey

I'm currently try to write a user script to filter a movie blog site. I want to hide entries which have an low IMDb rating. The following script works in the way that I could filter the IMDB links with low rating. But I want to remove the whole div.

```js
var aTags = document.getElementsByTagName("a");

for (var i = 0; i < aTags.length; i++) {
  if (aTags[i].textContent.includes("IMDb")) {
    var rating = aTags[i].textContent;
    // ...
    if (rating <= 6.5) {
      aTags[i].remove();
    }
  }
}
```

The selector looks like this:

```css
div.content > div.subcontent > p:nth-child(4) > a:contains('IMDb')
```

The parent element i.e.`div.content` should be removed.

I also tried this in the last if:

```js
var lowRatingDiv = document.getElementsByClassName("content")[i];
lowRatingDiv.remove();
```

Which results in a "Cannot read property 'remove' of undefined"

Comment: Jave you tried using `let i` instead of `var i`. I think it is trying to remove `aTags[aTags.length-1]` instead. See: [_Quick Tip - Use let with for Loops in JavaScript_](https://wesbos.com/for-of-es6)

Comment: If you know the structure, why not use the `parentNode` property? Like so: `aTags[i].parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.remove()`

Comment: Can you share the blog site or an example of it?
How do you get `ratings` out of the `textContent`?!?  Seems like a string/not a Number...

Answer (score 0):

## `HTMLElement#parentElement` to reach the `<div>`

If the structure was always the same, you could potentially utilize the `.parentElement` property to access the `div` at the top of your HTML structure to remove it.

For example:

```js
if (rating <= 6.5) {
  aTags[i].parentElement.parentElement.parentElement.remove();
}
```

Comment: You could also create a function that takes the child and an ancestor selector and iteratively/recursively call `parentElement` until you find said ancestor.

Answer (score 0):

You can iteratively (or recursively) locate the correct ancestor by it's class if you do not know the direct path between it and the child.

```js
const removeParent = (node, ancestorClass) => {
  while (node != null) {
    if (node.classList.contains(ancestorClass)) {
      node.remove();
      return true;
    }
    node = node.parentElement;
  }
  return false;
};

const removeLowRatings = () => {
  let selector = 'div.content > div.subcontent > p:nth-child(4) > a';
  Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(selector))
    .filter(el => el.textContent.includes('IMDb'))
    .forEach(el => removeParent(el, 'content'));
  }

removeLowRatings();
```

```css
*           { margin: 0.125rem;                              }
.wrapper    { border: red solid thin;     padding: 0.125rem; }
.content    { border: green solid thin;   padding: 0.125rem; }
.subcontent { border: blue solid thin;    padding: 0.125rem; }
p           { border: magenta solid thin; padding: 0.125rem; }
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <!-- This first element gets removed... -->
  <div class="content">
    <div class="subcontent">
      <p>1</p>
      <p>2</p>
      <p>3</p>
      <p><a href="#">IMDb</a></p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <div class="subcontent">
      <p>1</p>
      <p>2</p>
      <p>3</p>
      <p>4</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

### A more dynamic solution

Alternatively, you can compare the selectors. This is more dynamic, but it has a little more overhead. David Walsh has a great workaround for this.

```js
// Adapted from: https://davidwalsh.name/element-matches-selector
const selectorMatches = (el, selector) => {
    const p = Element.prototype;
    const f = p.matches || p.webkitMatchesSelector || p.mozMatchesSelector || p.msMatchesSelector || function(s) {
        return [].indexOf.call(document.querySelectorAll(s), this) !== -1;
    };
    return f.call(el, selector);
}

const removeParent = (node, ancestorSelector) => {
  while (node != null) {
    if (selectorMatches(node, ancestorSelector)) {
      node.remove();
      return true;
    }
    node = node.parentElement;
  }
  return false;
};

const removeLowRatings = () => {
  let selector = 'div.content > div.subcontent > p:nth-child(4) > a';
  Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(selector))
    .filter(el => el.textContent.includes('IMDb'))
    .forEach(el => removeParent(el, '.content')); // I am using the selector!
  }

removeLowRatings();
```

```css
*           { margin: 0.125rem;                              }
.wrapper    { border: red solid thin;     padding: 0.125rem; }
.content    { border: green solid thin;   padding: 0.125rem; }
.subcontent { border: blue solid thin;    padding: 0.125rem; }
p           { border: magenta solid thin; padding: 0.125rem; }
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <!-- This first element gets removed... -->
  <div class="content">
    <div class="subcontent">
      <p>1</p>
      <p>2</p>
      <p>3</p>
      <p><a href="#">IMDb</a></p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <div class="subcontent">
      <p>1</p>
      <p>2</p>
      <p>3</p>
      <p>4</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```